# React-native make List-FlatList with Texts scrollable

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-native-flatlist

I have a problem with enabling scrollability with List class of the React-native. You can see my structure below:

```
<Container>
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View style={styles.content}>
                <View style={styles.mainBoxes}></View>
                <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 24, paddingTop: 20}}>Title</Text>
                <List>
                    <FlatList
                        data=...
                        renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                            <View>
                                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20}}>{item.content}</Text>
                                <List>
                                    <FlatList
                                        data=...
                                        renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                                            <View>
                                                <Text style={{fontSize: 18, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 40, paddingRight: 20}}>...</Text>
                                            </View>
                                        )}
                                        keyExtractor=...
                                    />
                                </List>
                            </View>
                            )}
                        keyExtractor=...
                    />
                </List>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
</Container>
```

The part that I want to be scrollable is from the text right before the first list (6th line in the code), until the end of the list. I have tried using ScrollView, adding/removing flex: 1, but I had no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you adding List with flatList. Flatlist itself is scrollable.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The List is indeed redundant, but even without the list, the problem remains.

Comment: try after removing  <container> tag too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the TouchableWithoutFeedback class, so removing it solved the issue.